# No injection $Ord \to A$

Tags: set-theory

Let $A$ be a set. Why is it true that there is no injection $Ord \to A$ without the axiom of choice, where $Ord$ is the class of all ordinals?

Comment: If $\alpha $ injects into $ A $, there is a well-ordering of a subset of $ A $ in type $\alpha $.

Comment: So you are being asked to construct the Hartogs number?

Comment: @ZhenLin I was reading a proof of the Cantor-Bendixson theorem and it was claimed on page 26:http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~byorgey/settheory/08-more-real-line.pdf

Comment: Because if there were, $Ord$ would have to form a set by replacement (which is impossible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that there were a formula $\varphi(x,y)$ defining an injection from $\mathsf{Ord}$ to a set $A$. Then its range would be a set, and it would be easy enough to write down the appropriate formula defining the inverse of that injection, so the [axiom schema of replacement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement) would imply that $\mathsf{Ord}$ was a set. $\mathsf{AC}$ doesn’t enter into it.